# Restore-SPSite : Could not deserialize site from C:\sitebackup\site.back . System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, restore

Hi when I restore a sitecollection in staging server i get below error in uls logs and restore command not successful.

Backup taken from production and content database size is 28GB
Backup-SPSite "http://xxx/sitecol1 " -Path "C:\sitebackup\site.bak" -NoSiteLock

**Restore**

```
Restore-SPSite "http://website1" -Path "C:\sitebackup\site.bak" -Force -DatabaseServer "TestDB1" -DatabaseName "WSS_Content_new"
```

> Restore-SPSite :
> 0x80070003
> **IN ULS lOGS:** Powershell (0x3F88) 0x4C78 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade BACKUP 0000 DEBUG Error serializing, caller should rollback
> transaction and any intermediate changesco.
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The instance of the
> SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource  at this
> time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the
> database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for
> this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError
>
> **Could not deserialize site from C:\sitebackup\site.bak . System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):** The instance of the
> SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK resource  at this
> time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer active users. Ask the
> database administrator to check the lock and memory configuration for
> this instance, or to check for long-running transactions.      at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)      at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
> completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
> Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)      at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlCommand
> command)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.Sql.SqlPartitionManager.Deserialize(SqlSession
> sqlSess, SPDatabase database, BinaryReader br, Object context)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode,
> Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)
> ClientConnectionId:5f4ea8cd-8c98-4ba9-aa82-c6dc5b6f35f1  Error
> Number:1204,State:4,Class:19

Comment: The file extension should be ".bak" and not ".back".

Comment: sorry it was .bak file

Comment: @user3520155, please is possible to detail your action? Do you make migration from SharePoint minor version to major version? And, the database that you try to restore the Site Collection belongs to some SharePoint Web Application?

Comment: when i do other small size site collection backups from production sharepoint farm to restore in staging its successful, but this large size site collection backup not restoring